# How did the function "Save As…" change to "Duplicate"?

Tags: macos, iwork, file

I recently noticed that within Pages ('09), Numbers ('09), Keynote ('09),
the menu entry:

- File > Save As…

had been replaced by a new one:

- File > Duplicate

On the other hand I still use this function within some other applications like LibreOffice (4.2.3.3) without a problem.
I suspect this change isn't a system wide one.

I didn't get any notice of this change of a key function in file management within any recent upgrade.

---

When did this change appear?

Which upgrade performed this change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was changed in Lion along with the introduction of Auto Save and Versions. Save As is still available by holding <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> whilst in the menus.

Comment: Thank you for predicting and answering my next question :).